# $scope does not return any value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to access $scope variable inside my controller . when I console my $scope it shows number of values but when I try to access it via $scope. it return undefined.

I have attached screen shot of $scope

[image]

Here you can see it have $id, $parent , templateUrl but when i am trying to access it via $scope.id , $scope.parent , $scope.templateUrl it return undefined .

**Edited :**

I am trying to access template url . actually I want to attach some params with template url so that I can get them in my backend function

**here is my code :**

```
brainframeApp.config(
    ['$interpolateProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider', '$routeProvider',
    function($interpolateProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider,
    $routeProvider) {
        //configuring angularjs symbos to not to conflict with Django template symbols
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{$');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('$}');
        //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
        // setup CSRF support
        $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
        $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
        console.log("TestDavy: App");
        //The route provider
        $routeProvider.
          when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/static/engine/partials/listbrainframes.html',
            controller: 'brainframeCtrl'
          }).
          when('/brainframe/', {
            templateUrl: '/views/post.html',
            controller: 'brainframeCtrlx'
          }).
          when('/brainframe/:id', {
            templateUrl: '/views/post.html',
            controller: 'brainframeCtrlx'
          }).
          otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
          });
}]);
```

**my controller :**

```
brainframeAppControllers.controller('brainframeCtrlx', 
    ['$scope', '$routeParams', function($scope, $routeParams) {
        //console.log($scope.parent);
        //$scope.templateUrl = 'views/post.html?id='+$routeParams.id;
    //console.log($scope);
    $scope.templateUrl = 'views/post.html?id='+$routeParams.id;
    //console.log($scope.templateUrl);
}]);
```

Comment: Where are you "trying to access it as $scope" from?

Comment: You can access it by $scope.$id and $scope.$parent but still what do you want from it  ?

Comment: @squiroid I am trying to access template url . actually I want to attach some params with template url so that I can get them in my backend function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I put console.log on `$scope`, am able to see only these properties:

```
["$$childTail", "$$childHead", "$$nextSibling", "$$watchers", "$$listeners", "$$listenerCount", "$id", "$$ChildScope", "$parent", "$$prevSibling"]
```

If you want to access the template URL inside your controller:

```
brainframeApp.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on( "$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
       $rootScope.templateUrl = next.$$route.templateUrl;
    });
});
```

Now inside your controller, inject $rootScope and get the template URL

```
$rootScope.templateUrl
```

Comment: a general question , let say I have two controllers and I want to user a variable value defined in first controller into the second one. is it possible ?

Comment: Mostly if you want to share data among controllers its better to create a service/factory for that. But you can also share the properties using `$controller('ControllerName',{scope:scope})`

Comment: this is a good example http://gonzalo123.com/2014/09/08/sharing-scope-between-controllers-with-angularjs/

Comment: As i mentioned they've used `factory` for that purpose :)

Comment: I am not able to use `Scopes.get()`  it says undefined . Scopes do not have get function

Comment: did you declare it in the service? Please refer that example. in the return object they are exposing both store as well as get. Also remember to inject Scopes service in your corresponding controller